# Browser field tipified suggestion

Tags: html, browser, autocomplete

I understand that you as programmer can tipify the suggestion of the browser for each field. e.g: this field is email and the inserted value will be suggested (in the future) only for email fields

Does that realy exists? how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting place for local storage and session storage can be found [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/).

However, if all you are looking for is basic form field autocomplete, take a gander at these resources from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533032%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [Mozilla](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Form+autocomplete).

Comment: Are the tag-attr shown in Microsoft page cross-browser? In Mozilla's page only says how to use it "as user". Not as programmer.